# How to remove selected item text from react native dropdown?

Tags: react-native, dropdown, selecteditem

I use   react-native-material-dropdown and when I select an item, the selected item is visible. How to make it disappear to avoid getting text over an image like this :
Thanks a lot for any help !

[image]

```
        <View style={[styles.centeredView, {marginTop:0}]}>
      <MaterialDropdown
        data={data_dropdown}
        pickerStyle={styles.dropdownPickerStyle}
        affixTextStyle={{ fontFamily: "FunctionLH" }}
        itemTextStyle={{ fontFamily: "FunctionLH" }}
        labelTextStyle={{ fontFamily: "FunctionLH" }}
        containerStyle={styles.dropdownContainerStyle}
        itemCount={10}
        dropdownPosition={-4.5}
        underlineColor='transparent'
        labelExtractor={({ label }) => label}
        valueExtractor={({ value }) => value}
        propsExtractor={({ props }, index) => props}
        onChangeText={(value) => this.choiceAction(value)}
        useNativeDriver={true}
      />
      <Image
        source={require("../../assets/images/btn-filter-by-period.png")}
        style={{resizeMode: "contain",
                width: "95%",
                height: 50,
                borderRadius: 100 / 2,
                position: 'absolute',
                margin: 0,
                padding: 0,
                height:30,
                borderRadius:0}}/>
    </View>
```

Comment: set the text color to 'transparent'

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I already tried this. It makes everything transparent, even the list of the dropdown.

Comment: Is it possible to not show selected item in label ?